# constant stalks but not constant sheaf?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, sheaf-theory

In the coherent world we have the following: if X is reduced and F is a coherent sheaf on it, then if the rank of all fibres in constant then F is locally free.

I thought something similar held in the topological world but cannot seem to prove it.
In other words: is the following true?

> Let X be a topological space (say a manifold) and consider a sheaf of Q-vector spaces F. Assume also that F(U) is finite-dimensional for all opens U. Assume also that the stalk $F_x$ has dimension n for all $x \in X$. Then F is a locally constant sheaf.

I can easily show that for each $x$ there is a neighborhood $U$, with $F(U)$ of dimension n and such that, for any $x \in V \subset U$ the restriction $F(U) \to F(V)$ is an isomorphism. However, if $V$ is a subset of U *not* containing x, then I don't know to show that the restriction is an isomorphism (which is what's missing to show that the sheaf is actually locally constant).

Comment: Don't you need some kind of connectedness hypothesis on your neighbourhoods?

Comment: @ZhenLin: sure, assume all you want. Heck, assume $X = R$ even (from which I think a proof can be bootstrapped).

Comment: What about $j_!\mathbb{Q}_U\oplus i_*\mathbb{Q}_Z$ for $j:U\subset X$ an open subset and $i:Z\subset X$ the closed complement. This is not locally constant, is it ?

Comment: @user113969: see, I'm not supergreat with sheaves in the topological world. What is the stalk of $j_!\Q_U$ over a point $z \in Z$? Is it zero? I think you might be on to something.

Comment: @user125763 What I mean is, $F (V)$ is only guaranteed to be $n$-dimensional if $V$ is connected. Otherwise it is $n m$-dimensional, where $m$ is the number of connected components of $U$. (I assume $X$ is locally connected.)

Comment: @ZhenLin: you are right, I was implicitly (and subconsciously) making the assumption that all my neighborhoods were connected (or contractible even).

Comment: @user125763 yes the stalks of $j_!\mathbb{Q}_U$ are zero outside $U$ and are $\mathbb{Q}$ on $U$. Similarly the stalks of $i_*\mathbb{Q}_Z$ are zero outside of $Z$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ on $Z$. However, the constant sheaf does not split in general (ie $0\rightarrow j_!\mathbb{Q}_U\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}_X\rightarrow i_*\mathbb{Q}_Z\rightarrow 0$ is not a trivial extension in general).

Comment: sounds like U and Z should be connected components for this to be true! This must be a known fact!

Comment: Yes that's right, if $U$ and $Z$ both complementary clopens, the extension splits. In general (at least if $X$ and $Z$ are nice), this sequence induce the long exact sequence of cohomology with compact support.

Comment: @user113969 I think that's a valid counterexample, maybe even the complement of a point in $S^1$ would do it concretely. Do you want to write it up as an answer?

Answer (score 4):

Let $X$ be a (nice) topological space, $i:Z\subset X$ a closed subset and $j:U\subset X$ the open complement. The sheaves $\mathbb{Q}_X$ and $j_!\mathbb{Q}_U\oplus i_*\mathbb{Q}_Z$ are not isomorphic in general, for instance if $Z$ is a point in $X=S^1$ (they are obviously isomorphic when $U$ and $Z$ are complementary clopens).

However, both sheaves have the same stalks, namely $\mathbb{Q}$. This comes from the fact that $j_!\mathcal{F}_x=0$ if $x\not\in U$ and $j_!\mathcal{F}_x=\mathcal{F}_x$ for $x\in U$. Similarly, $i_*\mathcal{F}_x=0$ if $x\not\in Z$ and $i_*\mathcal{F}_x=\mathcal{F}_x$ for $x\in Z$.

Comment: The sheaves $\mathbb{Q}_X$ and $j_!\mathbb{Q}_U\oplus i_*\mathbb{Q}_Z$ are not isomorphic because if $V$ is an open set intersecting both $U$ and $Z$, then the restriction from $V$ to $V\setminus Z$ is zero in the second sheaf but not the first.